# Moving Row between sheets based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook that I am working on for our company and need a little help on this one. Normally I can figure things out pretty easy. In my worksheet there are several tabs the ones I am working with now are NEW, In Progress, On Hold, Scheduled and Complete. Permits are added to the New tab Via google form input, what I would like to happen that when the status changes in Column K is that it goes to the corresponding tab. I had this all set up in Excel but we are no longer allowed to use Excel at work. [TK's Daily Production](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0XSPVjaFVg3BxjvHOAXjkPtExMSpnDY1BOnWLhr040/edit#gid=1541668950) Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 0):

In sheet, click Tools > Script Editor.
Paste below code. This code assumes Column K has header 'status' and this column values have corresponding tabs = sheets in Spreadsheet. As an example, if Column K has value 'NEW', there must be a tab named 'NEW'. If you edit value in this column, say from 'NEW' to 'Complete', that row will be copied to 'Complete' tab and optionally deleted from 'NEW' tab if corresponding code is activated.

```
// onEdit trigger
function onEdit() {
  moveToTab();
}

function moveToTab() {
  // active SS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // active cell/range
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  // active column
  var col = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log(col);
  // active sheet
  var aSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // get active column header
  var header = aSheet.getRange(1,col,1,1).getValue();
  Logger.log(header);
  // here i assume, Column K has a header 'status'
  // change 'status' string to what you have as Column K header
  // if column is not 'status', do nothing
  if (header.toLowerCase() !== 'status') return;
  // get value
  var target = range.getValue();
  // trim and check there is a value
  if (target.toString().trim() === '') return;
  // do nothing if same sheet
  if (target.toString().toLowerCase() === aSheet.getName().toLowerCase()) return;
  // try {
    // try move
    // target sheet based on Column K value
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var tSheet = sheets.filter(function(sheet) {
      if (sheet.getName().toLowerCase() == target.toLowerCase()) return true;
      else return false;
    })[0];
    if (!tSheet) return;
    // active cell row
    var row = range.getRow();
    // get active row values
    var values = aSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, aSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    // append values to target row
    tSheet.appendRow(values[0]);
    // optionally delete row from old sheet
    // un-comment if required
    aSheet.deleteRow(row);
  // } catch(e) {}
}
```

Comment: I have done what you said to do but cannot get it to work what am I Missing ?

Comment: Do you have 'status' header in Column K, column whose values will be edited ? Plus, write here the names of the tabs, exactly as you have in spreadsheet. Those few corresponding to values in Column K.

Comment: yea Column K header is labeled as Status

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0XSPVjaFVg3BxjvHOAXjkPtExMSpnDY1BOnWLhr040/edit#gid=1030794896

Comment: ra89fi I have tried that as well and still nothing. I am probably missing something silly, I have posted a link to my workbook in previous post above if you want to look and see if im missing anything lol https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0XSPVjaFVg3BxjvHOAXjkPtExMSpnDY1BOnWLhr040/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's private. I don't have access.

Comment: try now https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0XSPVjaFVg3BxjvHOAXjkPtExMSpnDY1BOnWLhr040/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Found it. Looking.

Comment: Copy code and try again. If any error, copy its text and paste here. And remember to put words matching tab names in status column. Edit cell and press Enter in keyboard.

Comment: ok apparently im not doing something right. I have done everything you have said to do and nothing happens when I change the status in column K

Comment: Close the script tab and reload sheet tab in browser. Then try again.

Comment: In sheet, click **Tools > Script Editor**. Opens up script tab. In script click **Run > Run Function > moveToTab**. If it asks for permission, allow.

Comment: I dont get it still nothing

Comment: I got it I told you it was something SIMPLE..... works just fine THANKS for the help much APPRECIATED

Comment: Ok I have a conundrum going on here lol and I'm scratching my head. My sheet has columns A through O, My headers are on Row 3 and my trigger column is Col I labeled Issued to.  How do I change the  the following script to work :